# C++ reading from a multi-type csv file

Tags: c++, csv

I'm trying to use C++ to read from a file, which is structured like this:

```
frank, 80, 90
johnny, 10, 25
...
```

I made a loop to go through each line of the file, but every time I read the name string, the comma is included with the name (so instead of `frank` I get `frank,`).

My code in question is:

```
// var declarations
ifstream streamVar;
string name;
int num1, num2;

// there is a chunk of code that opens file and does error checking here

// this is the code that I'm having trouble with
streamVar >> name;
streamVar >> num1;
streamVar.ignore(100, ',');
streamVar >> num2;
```

How can I read these three values while ignoring the commas?

Comment: Can you post the code you use to read the file?

Comment: @Timo I've updated my question with the code I'm using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIRC the streams use space as a default delimiter and you will have to specify that ',' is another delimiter.

[Here's another question on SO regarding specifying delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4197697/c-ifstream-function-and-field-separators), that should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Must be because your code is wrong. Exactly how is anyone's guess since you failed to post it.

I've posted the code I use to [read and write CSV files in C++](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/files/reading-and-writing-csv-files-in-mfc). Perhaps that will be some help.